# how to create build server in ubuntu 16.04 with ip public ISP?

Tags: server, vps

i have a question, i think i always buy vps to access to the server computer, and i have an idea, how can my pc be a server?

For example, I have bought the internet + public IP package

So, how can I make the IP address can be accessed by the terminal on someone's computer like vps access?

suppose I have public ip 187.133.92.1,
how so that ip can access with port 22 and can remotely.

hope for help, I'm confused with keywords on Google regarding this problem.

I want the steps to be accessible via port 22,

I am now on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Comment: So you have a static IP address from your internet service provider? How is this computer connected to the internet? Via WiFi? Using Ethernet? With or without a router? Please edit your question and add new information in the question.

Comment: Install the openssh-server package to install an ssh server.  Note that default settings permits password access; most folks who don't like to be pwned will change the settings to permit key access only.